# Where is the module cache in golang?

Tags: go, vgo

When I enable gomodules and  build my go program then the required packages are downloaded.

But I cannot find them in `$GOPATH/src/` or in `$GOPATH/src/mod`.

Where are they stored?

```
export GO111MODULE=on
go mod init
go build main.go 
go: finding github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
...
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For Go 1.11, they are stored in

```
$GOPATH/pkg/mod
```

Comment: Note this is documented in `go help modules`

Comment: On Linux, if `$GOPATH` is empty. Modules are stored in `/home/<user>/go/pkg/mod`!

Comment: @ifnotak The same as macOS.

Comment: GOPATH doesn't make sense when go modules are enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67233153/224021 for a current answer.

Answer (score 14):

Run this in terminal

```
go env GOMODCACHE
```

[go env](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Print_Go_environment_information) - Print all Go environment information

go env NAME - Print specific env var.

Comment: You should include more of an explanation as part of your answer. The answer you provided is almost identical from an answer that was posted by Chris on Dec 30, 2020. Your answer should improve upon the existing answers.

Comment: I think this answer is the more accurate one for recent versions of go, and it does improve on Chris's answer.

Answer (score 10):

To determine cache locations, you can use go env:

```
go env|grep CACHE
```

To clean the caches, use `go clean -modcache` or `go clean -cache` depending on the type of cache to be cleared.

Comment: Thanks. `go help clean` also lists some other options.

Answer (score 7):

I'm on Macos 10.13.6, using `go1.11 darwin/amd64` and `echo $GOPATH` is empty.

I found my modules in `$HOME/go/pkg/mod`

Comment: do you have $GOPATH set to $HOME/go?

Comment: $GOPATH defaults to $HOME/go on Go 1.11 and forward.

Answer (score 7):

The module cache is stored in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`, or `$HOME/go/pkg/mod` if `$GOPATH` is not set.

**Note**: in general, the module cache is read-only, and is intended to be an immutable cache. As such, you should never try to edit things there, nor should you run `go` commands from inside the cache.

The module cache contains the zip files, unpacked module source code, as well as a VCS cache (when not using a proxy). The cache often contains multiple versions of a single dependency.

If you want to inspect the code of a dependency in the module cache, one shortcut is you can `cd` directly to the location of an unpacked dependency via:

```
cd $(go list -f '{{.Dir}}' -m github.com/foo/bar)
```

That asks [go list](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules) to report on the directory location of the module `github.com/foo/bar` within the module cache, defaulting to whatever version you currently are using in your current module.

Given the cache is intended to be immutable, a related question is how do you edit a dependency (e.g., if you want to add a debug log, or perhaps in preparation for sending an upstream fix for a dependency). A common solution at this point is to use [gohack](https://github.com/rogpeppe/gohack), which creates a mutable copy of a dependency (by default in `$HOME/gohack`, but the location is controlled by `$GOHACK` variable). `gohack`also sets your current `go.mod` file to have a [replace](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) directive to point to that mutable copy.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want clean up cache there is a command `go clean --modcache`

In case you just need to update some dependency you probably want to clean up information about this dependency from

- go.mod
- go.sum
- vendor/modules.txt