# Go mod is downloading well, but golint is failing on supposed downloaded dependencies

Tags: go, gitlab-ci, go-modules

In Gitlab CI, I need to specify `GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN`, as I have some private repositories. This works well for compile step.

But when I execute golint, it will download again all dependencies, and it will fail on private ones. I could add the same `git config` directive,

image: golang
variables:
  PACKAGE_PATH: /go/src/gitlab.com/company/sam/daemon
  PACKAGE_API_NAME: registry.gitlab.com/company/sam/daemon
  REGISTRY_URL: https://registry.gitlab.com
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  GO111MODULE: "on"

.anchors:
  - &inject-gopath
      mkdir -p $(dirname ${PACKAGE_PATH})
      && ln -s ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} ${PACKAGE_PATH}
      && cd ${PACKAGE_PATH}

```
compile:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - *inject-gopath
    - git config --global url."https://oauth:${GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf https://gitlab.com
    - go mod tidy
  script: GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -o release/daemon .
  artifacts:
    name: "binary-$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
    paths:
      - $GOPATH/pkg/mod/
    expire_in: 1 hour

lint:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apt install -y curl git
    - go get github.com/golang/lint
    - *inject-gopath
  script:
    - $GOPATH/bin/golint -set_exit_status $(go list ./...)
  allow_failure: true
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126923/where-is-the-module-cache-in-golang) that go modules were cached in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` but it doesn't seem to work

Any idea how should I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure to use a module build? Did you set GO111MODULE=on?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I have go modules output, so there is no doubt about it

Comment: You might need gitlab to cache the dependencies between jobs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-archiving-and-extracting-works

Comment: I used to do it with artifacts, with vendor folder, and it was working well.... I could give it a try

Comment: Are you certain `golint` supports modules? (https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/409)

Comment: Yep, it sounds that there is still not a full support of modules with lint

Comment: What does your `inject-gopath` look like?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman I updated the code with inject-gopath, and other variables

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab interprets all paths as relative to the project root, so if your project is `myproject`, `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/` translates to `myproject/$GOPATH/pkg/mod/`, but the location where the go tool actually actually installs the packages is `/$GOPATH/pkg/mod/` (directly under root).

You can work around this by setting the GOPATH to a location within the project directory; e.g.

```
export GOPATH="$CI_PROJECT_DIR/pkg/mod"
```

Then, you can use this path throughout your pipeline.